# Prove that, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f_n(z)=|z|e^{in\arg(z)}$ is Lipschitz with constant n.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Suppose $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f_n:(\mathbb{C},|\cdot|)\rightarrow(\mathbb{C},|\cdot|)$ is defined via the map $z\mapsto |z|e^{in\arg(z)}$. How do you show that $f_n$ is a Lipschitz map with Lipschitz constant n? I know if $f$ maps the unit ball to the unit ball and $n=1$ that $f$ is Lipschitz with constant 1; can be see as an application of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. However I am not sure how to extend this. Naturally here $|\cdot|$ denoted the Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already [observed by Oliver Diaz](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3697223/42969) it suffices to show
that
$$ \tag{*}
|f_n(z) - 1 | \le n^2 |z-1| 
$$
because of the homogeneity of the function. For $z= re^{i \phi}$ this is equivalent
to
$$
\begin{align}
 &r^2 - 2r \cos(n \phi) + 1 \le n^2 \bigl[r^2 - 2r \cos(\phi) + 1 \bigr] \\
\iff &(r-1)^2 + 2r (1-\cos(n\phi)) \le  n^2 \left[(r-1)^2 + 2r(1- \cos(\phi))\right] \\
\iff &(r-1)^2 + r \sin^2\left(\frac{n \phi}{2}\right) \le  n^2 \left[(r-1)^2 + r\sin^2\left(\frac{ \phi}{2}\right)\right] \, .
\end{align}
$$
We see that it suffices to prove
$$
\begin{align}
 &\sin^2\left(\frac{n \phi}{2}\right) \le  n^2 \sin^2\left( \frac{\phi}{2} \right) \\
\iff & \left|\sin\left(\frac{n \phi}{2}\right) \right|\le  n \left| \sin\left( \frac{\phi}{2} \right) \right|
\end{align}
$$
and that can easily be shown with induction, see for example [How to prove by induction that $|\sin(nx)| \leq n|\sin x|$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067749/how-to-prove-by-induction-that-sinnx-leq-n-sin-x).

One can also see that *equality* holds in $(*)$ for $n \ge 2$ if and only if $r=1$ and $\sin\left( \frac{\phi}{2} \right) = 0$, that is if and only if $z=1$.

Comment: The answers to that question are actually showing $|\sin(nx)|\le n\,|x|$ (the question seems to have been changed after the answers were written).

Comment: @robjohn: At least the first part of the [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2372278) proves the inequality needed here. But I have found another reference now.

Comment: It's okay, I took your suggestion and proved it by induction.

Comment: Ah, the accepted answer *does* answer the question properly as it was written a month later ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a suggestion. It is too impractical to put this as a comment:

Without loss of generalization, suppose  $z=Re^{i\theta}$, $w=re^{i\psi}$ with $R\geq r$ so that $\rho=\frac{r}{R} \leq 1$. Then, the question is whether

$$
|1-\rho e^{in(\psi-\theta)}|\leq n|1-\rho e^{i(\psi-\theta)}|
$$ 
for all $1<\rho\leq1$ and $\psi,\theta$. In other words, if is true that

$$
1+\rho^2 - 2\rho\cos(n\varphi) \leq n^2(1+\rho^2 -2\rho\cos\varphi)\tag{1}\label{one}
$$

for all $0<\rho\leq1$ and $0\leq\varphi\leq2\pi$. Here is a plot ($n=12$)
that suggests
$$
g_\rho(\varphi)=\frac{n^2\cos\varphi -\cos n\varphi}{n^2-1}\leq 1 \tag{2}\label{two}
$$

[image]

I had not been worked out the proof of $\eqref{two}$, which would imply $\eqref{one}$ since $1\leq \frac{1+\rho^2}{2\rho}$, but is should be straight forward for you to to do this by showing that  $0$, $\pi$, and $2\pi$ are the only critical points of $g_\rho$. This may require a careful analysis of the  values of $g'_\rho$ around those critical points in addition to some convexity argument

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look properly tomorrow morning to see if I can get this idea to work! I tried the idea with bounded Jacobian and can get it to work in any ball B(0,r) for r>0 but not for the entire plane. Will keep you updated on any further progress.

Comment: I have been attempting to show this today. My first question is how to prove $0, \pi$ and $2\pi$ are the only critical points. I keep going in circles.

Comment: Thank you that does now make sense! I believe I may have made progress another way. I will type now and post as an answer as too big to put in a comment. If you could have a look to verify that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Sadly upon typing up my solution I noticed I made a slight mistake in one of the inequalities which causes it to fail. I have managed to show it for $\rho\leq \frac{n^2-2n+1}{n^2-1}$.

Comment: I believe I have managed to show it. Thank you very much for you help

Answer (score 0):

What the function actually *looks* like is that it sends $z$ to the point on the circle centered at the origin, with radius $|z|$, to a point with argument $\arg(z^n) = n \arg (z)$. Thus for any $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$, we have a diagram that looks roughly like this (where $x',y'$ are $f_n(x),f_n(y)$):

[image: Like this]

Thus it suffices to prove the following lemma:

> **Lemma:** In a triangle with angle $\alpha$ in between sides of length $a,b$ and third side $c$, the triangle with angle $n\alpha$ in between sides of lengths $a,b$ and third side $c'$ satisfies $c'\le nc$.

Firstly, we prove this lemma for $n$ odd. If we reflect the initial triangle $n-1$ times, it's easy to see that the lemma is true -- the shortest path between two points is a straight line, as can be seen in this example when $n=5$.:

[image: example for n = 5]

Next, if the lemma is true for $n=i$ and $n=j$, it is certainly true for $n=ij$, by applying it twice. This follows if we let the side length $c_n=g_n(a,b,\alpha)$ be a function of $a,b$ and the included angle. Then $$c_{ij}\ge ic_j\ge ijc_j,$$ where the first inequality follows from the assumption that it is true for $n=i$, and the latter for $n=j$.

Thus it suffices to prove the case when $n=2$.

In this case, we have:

$$c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\alpha}$$
$$c'=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(2\alpha)}$$

So this is equivalent to proving that $$2^2(a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\alpha)\ge a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(2\alpha).$$
Rearrange this to get
$$3\frac{a^2+b^2}{2ab}\ge 4\cos\alpha - \cos(2\alpha).$$

But $a^2+b^2\ge 2ab$, so $\frac{a^2+b^2}{2ab}\ge1$, and thus it suffices to show that $$3\ge 4\cos\alpha-\cos(2\alpha).$$

Using the double angle formula for cos ($\cos(2\alpha)=2\cos^2\alpha-1$), this simplifies directly to $$2(\cos\alpha-1)^2\ge0,$$

and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Let$$
f(z)=|z|e^{in\arg(z)}\tag1
$$
For $n=1$, $f(z)=z$, so assume $n\ge2$.

Define $r=\frac{2|z||w|}{|z|^2+|w|^2}\le1$ and $\theta=\arg(z)-\arg(w)\in[-\pi,\pi]$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{|f(z)-f(w)|^2}{|z-w|^2}
&=\frac{|z|^2+|w|^2-2|z||w|\cos(n(\arg(z)-\arg(w)))}{|z|^2+|w|^2-2|z||w|\cos(\arg(z)-\arg(w))}\tag{2a}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{1-r\cos(n\theta)}{1-r\cos(\theta)}\tag{2b}\\
&=1+r\frac{\cos(\theta)-\cos(n\theta)}{1-r\cos(\theta)}\tag{2c}\\
&\le1+r\left|\frac{\cos(\theta)-\cos(n\theta)}{1-r\cos(\theta)}\right|\tag{2d}\\
&\le1+\left|\frac{\cos(\theta)-\cos(n\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)}\right|\tag{2e}\\
&=1+\left|\frac{1-\cos(n\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)}-1\right|\tag{2f}\\[3pt]
&\le n^2\tag{2g}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)
$\text{(2b)}$: apply the definitions of $r$ and $\theta$
$\text{(2c)}$: algebra
$\text{(2d)}$: [Triangle Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)
$\text{(2e)}$: $r\le1$
$\text{(2f)}$: algebra
$\text{(2g)}$: $0\le\frac{1-\cos(n\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)}\le n^2$

---

**$\boldsymbol{0\le\frac{1-\cos(n\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)}\le n^2}$**

Since $\cos(x)$ is even, we need only consider $0\lt\theta\le\pi$.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\frac{1-\cos(n\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)}
&=\frac{n(1-\cos(\theta))\sin(n\theta)-(1-\cos(n\theta))\sin(\theta)}{(1-\cos(\theta))^2}\tag{3a}\\
&=\frac{\sin(\theta)\sin(n\theta)}{(1-\cos(\theta))^2}(n\tan(\theta/2)-\tan(n\theta/2))\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$
Since $\tan(x)$ is convex, for $0\lt\theta\le\frac\pi{n}$,
$$
\overbrace{\ \sin(n\theta)\ }^{\ge0}\overbrace{(n\tan(\theta/2)-\tan(n\theta/2))}^{\le0}\le0\tag4
$$
For $\frac\pi{n}\lt\theta\le\frac{2\pi}n$,
$$
\overbrace{\ \sin(n\theta)\ }^{\le0}(\overbrace{n\tan(\theta/2)}^{\ge0}-\overbrace{\tan(n\theta/2)}^{\le0})\le0\tag5
$$
Thus, for $0\lt\theta\le\frac{2\pi}n$, inequalities $(3)$, $(4)$, and $(5)$ show that $\frac{1-\cos(n\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)}$ is decreasing and the limit as $\theta\to0$ is $n^2$. Therefore,
$$
0\le\frac{1-\cos(n\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)}\le n^2\tag6
$$
For $\frac{2\pi}n\lt\theta\le\pi$, we have $\frac8{n^2}\le\frac2{\pi^2}\theta^2\le1-\cos(\theta)\le\frac12\theta^2$. Therefore,
$$
0\le\frac{1-\cos(n\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)}\le\frac{n^2}4\tag7
$$
Inequalities $(6)$ and $(7)$ show that $0\le\frac{1-\cos(n\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)}\le n^2$.

---

**Another approach to $\boldsymbol{0\le\frac{1-\cos(n\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)}\le n^2}$**

Martin R mentions that we can use the relation $1-\cos(x)=2\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)$.

As he mentions, induction can be used to prove
$$
|\sin(nx)|\le n\,|\sin(x)|\tag8
$$
$(8)$ obviously holds for $n=0$, so assume it holds for some $n$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
|\sin((n+1)x)|
&=|\sin(nx)\cos(x)+\cos(nx)\sin(x)|\tag{9a}\\
&\le|\sin(nx)\cos(x)|+|\cos(nx)\sin(x)|\tag{9b}\\
&\le|\sin(nx)|+|\sin(x)|\tag{9c}\\
&\le n|\sin(x)|+|\sin(x)|\tag{9d}\\
&=(n+1)|\sin(x)|\tag{9e}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $(8)$ holds for all $n\ge0$.

$(8)$ implies that
$$
0\le\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{n\theta}2\right)}{\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)}\le n^2\tag{10}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
0\le\frac{1-\cos(n\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)}\le n^2\tag{11}
$$